# how can i make show only last 3 rows?

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to find a solution to make my php script show only the last 3 entries in a row but all i can find is how to show the first entries not the last 3. any ideas?

this is the script that shows the entries:

```
<?php   
    // Grab the data from our people table
    $sql = "select * from people";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not access DB: " . mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<div class=\"picture\">";
        echo "<p>";
        // Note that we are building our src string using the filename from the database
        echo "<img src=\"content/uploads/" . $row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" /><br />";
        echo $row['fname'] . " " . "<br />" . "<br />" . $row['lname'] . "<br />";
        echo "</p>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: just do reverse `ORDER BY`

Comment: Just use a proper query like `SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3` given your primary key is `id`

Comment: `select * from people order by primary_key desc limit 3`, where primary key is from your table

Comment: Can you use `select * from people ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3` to limit it in the sql query?

Comment: Basic research is OK and even encouraged.

Comment: sorry for this guys, i'm pretty new to php and mysql and for some reason i kept getting sollutions which only showed the first few entries of the database and for a noob as me it's not always easy to find the right codes to do certain things... so please don't be hard on me please... and thanks for the help it did work like a charm :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3";
```

`id=>`is your column name you you might have to change this

and dont use `mysql` function as they are depricated and soon going to be dropped. Learn `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: thx a lot :) but excuse for asking as a noob at this, but what are the coding differences of mysql qnd mysqi? is there a lot of difference? guess i'm starting to learn mysql at the wrong time...

Comment: aha i see, thanks for the info :) i'll look into that when i finnish this page and see what needs changing then :) cause i still need to figure out some stuff...

Answer (score 3):

Just do reverse `ORDER BY`, ie. if your table is ordered by column `id`, then do `ORDER BY id DESC` and then use `LIMIT 3`:

```
$sql = "select * from people ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3";
```

And PS, **mysql_*** are deprecated...